# Most reliable way to find persistence statement or store name in producer

Tags: codefluent

In my model I have a store named **MyModel.MyStore**. Once the BOM producer run, it becomes a constant whose name is **MyModel_MyStoreStoreName**

Given a simple producer, I want to add the persistence statement; usually

```
CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence persistence = CodeFluentContext.Get(MyModel.Models.Constants.MyModel_MyStoreStoreName).Persistence;
```

From the entity I've seen I can get the defined store name, but I didn't find any way to have the final store name as constant; i.e. MyModel_MyStoreStoreName;

One way I found is to iterate through methods to filter statement I'm interested in. What is the most reliable way to fetch/build this persistence statement ?

Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Business Object Model Producer (BOM) use the following method to generate the name of the constant:

```
CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomLocal.GetStoreFieldName(entity.Store.Name)
```